# How to organize the vuex with websocket mutations

Tags: vue.js, websocket, vuex

I use vue+vuex+vue-native-websocket.
According to the documentation to handle websocket messages with vuex I should use SOCKET_... mutations.

For the moment I handle all the messages in *store/index.js* file, like that:

```
mutations: {
...
SOCKET_ONMESSAGE(): {
    switch(message.cmd) {
        case 'userRsp'
        ...
        case 'connectionRsp'
        ...
        case 'otherDataRsp'
        etc.
    }
}
```

What I want to is to handle all user related data in *user.js* vuex module, all connection data in *connections.js* vuex module.

Should I use SOCKET_ONMESSAGE inside each of these components? In this case according to my testing ON_MESSAGE will be called even for the module the message was not for.

Answer (score 2):

In the [vue-native-websocket readme](https://github.com/nathantsoi/vue-native-websocket#with-format-json-enabled):

> **With format: `'json'` enabled**
>
> [...]
>
> If there is a `.namespace` on the data, the message is sent to this
>   `namespaced: true` store (be sure to turn this on in the store module).
>
> If there is a `.mutation` value in the response data, the corresponding
>   mutation is called with the name `SOCKET_[mutation value]`
>
> If there is an `.action` value in the response data ie. `action: 'customerAdded'`, the corresponding action is called by name:
>
> ```
> actions: {
>   customerAdded (context) {
>     console.log('action received: customerAdded')
>   }
> }
> ```

When using the `json` format option:

```
Vue.use(VueNativeSock, 'ws://localhost:9090', { format: 'json' })
```

You can then pass the `namespace` and `mutation` or `action` name in the response and it will call the right function in your store module.

> Does it mean that the backend should insert namespace property to the response?

Yes. E.g. the backend should send `namespace: "user"` in the data to call the module of the same name.

---

> isn't it a bad practice when the backend defines the handler in frontend who should handle the message?

Is your backend meant to be used by multiple applications? Ones that you're not building yourself? If not, the backend and the frontend are the same application.

You could avoid being too verbose in the backend by only passing a `namespace` property and letting the frontend deal with it, but it would be easier to just tell the action as well. These are generic property names so it's not too coupled.

Comment: Thanks a lot Emile. I read it before, but it is a bit complicated for me right now.  
_If there is a .namespace on the data, the message is sent to this  namespaced: true store (be sure to turn this on in the store module)._
Does it mean that the backend should insert _namespace_ property to the response?  And what is the behaviour when there are number of modules which are namespaced:true? Which one will receive the message?

Comment: @Alex the backend should send `namespace: "user"` in the data to call the module of the same name.

Comment: Now I got it. Will try. Thanks again.
I thought about that... but isn't it a bad practice when the backend defines the handler in frontend who should handle the message?

Comment: @AlexanderCharkov I updated my answer to address your comments.

Comment: finally I have reimplemented my vuex store. Thanks for fast and very descriptive answers. You helped me a lot.